# Runtime Exception in java code on using Long.valueOf() function

Tags: java, exception, command-line-arguments

```java
public class testforfun {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try{
            String a=args[0];
            String b=args[1];
            long c= Long.valueOf(a);
            long d= Long.valueOf(b);
            // long d=b+f;
            System.out.println(c+d);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my java code to take 2 command line arguments and print it.

When I am giving command line arguments like this :

> javac testforfun.java

> java testforfun 34.678 46.322

it is giving runtime exception like this

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "34.5343"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:711)
        at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1163)
        at testforfun.main(testforfun.java:7)
```

I don't understand why. And also to mention that when I pass integer values in command line arguments it shows an exception but at least gives the result.

Comment: `34.678` is floating point number so it can't be properly stored in `long`. You want `double` or `float`.

Comment: `Long` is a data type for whole numbers. It cannot contain fractions. Therefor `"34.5343"` cannot be parsed into a `Long`.

Comment: It is telling you (correctly) that `34.5343` is not a `long`.  It is a representation of a mathematical real number, not an integer.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri the first call is a call to `javac`, it does not run the code, so no `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

Comment: Replace `Long.valueOf(X)` with `Double.valueOf(X)`. Numbers with decimal places cannot be stored in a `Long` and will thus throw an Exception if you try to convert it to one.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments you cannot parse `decimal` value to `long`.

you need to convert the `String` value into `double` first and then you can convert it into either `int` or `long`. Eg:

```
long c = Double.valueOf(a).longValue(); //you can pass integer value also
```

From [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longValue())

> Returns the value of this Double as a long (by casting to type long).

Answer (score 0):

Your string arguments contain decimal points and you can not convert them to Long type directly, first convert them to Double then convert result to Long, so conversion would be as following:

```
(long)Double.parseDouble("34.5343")
```

And corrected method would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create va
    try{
        String a=args[0];
        String b=args[1];
        long c=  (long)Double.parseDouble(a);
        long d=  (long)Double.parseDouble(b);
        System.out.println(c+d);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```